# JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF 2.0 and I am planning to use Eclipse as the IDE and Tomcat as servletcontainer. Are there any good tutorials for this?

Answer (score 5):

There's one at [Coreservlets.com](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/) and another one in [Eclipse User Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html)

If you are open to using Glassfish instead of Tomcat, there's another one at [balusc.blogspot.com](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html).