# Java EE: EJB vs JavaBean? How to organize my classes in a web project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans

I developed a Java application with three classes and a main.
I would have a web interface in order to replace this main.
Example : a function (in one of my classes) is called by a HTML button and its result is visible in a combo list.

Then, I used Java EE but, after reading severals tutorials, I begin to mix everything.
My classes must be modified to respect the Java EE model?
I understand that it must be either an EJB or a JavaBean.
How to know what type they belong?

Comment: You can find the Java EE 7 tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/

Answer (score 0):

A bean is a java object managed by a container. The container is the environment in which is deployed your project. There is various possible container, Spring, servlet container, Java EE one...

The same java class may be a managed bean if deployed in a JSF project or a CDI one ; or an EJB bean if deployed in an EJB project ;  or a spring bean if your application is using spring IOC container, it's just a matter of configuration (using annotation or XML configuration).

To deploy your project as a web project you need a web server (tomcat, jetty...) or a Java EE one (glassfish, jboss...) or a lightweight http server (https://github.com/CodeStory/fluent-http for example).

I'd advise to use tomcat and the jsf framework to begin according to your requierement ([JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547325/jsf-2-0-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-tomcat)). Otherwise you could try tomcat with rest services exposed to a javascript client (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)

For information, have a look to BalusC anwser about JavaEE : [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee?lq=1)

Good learning

Comment: A JavaBean doesn't have to be managed by a container. It's just some naming conventions etc.

Comment: :D a purist. You're perfectly right but the main interest is to allow the object manipulation per the environment: framework, container, editor, etc... a bean alone is just a POJO